# Invoke system contact app and retrieve data android

Tags: android, android-contacts

Im developing an application where in I have 2 text views and a button.
when I click the button, it should open default system contacts application and upon selecting a contact, it should display the name and number in the text fields respectively.
Now I have implemented `ContactsContract` and `getContentResolver`. But, I have seen other apps having this feature, which is quite easy because you need not create a list view and stuffs.
Now how do I start? how do I invoke default contact app and retrieve data from it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the details about your problem, but I am pretty sure that you need to use an Implicit Intent (because the Contacts app may be different on different devices).  Hopefully this page [will](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html) help.

You may need to start by using this code:

```
Intent i = new Intent();   // Declare intent
// Start the intent
startActivity(i);
```

You may want to use ACTION_GET_CONTENT.

Comment: well ,if you see call reminder. It has that feature where in it pops up default contact app and retrieves data from there. thats exactly what i want to implement. Im new to android, so how do i start?

Comment: Updated answer.  This is all I can really help you with--I'm still learning android development.

Comment: this will start an activity, but i specifically want only the contact display part to be shown. and upon selecting it should reflect in textviews

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the replies. I found out that this is what i need. 
`Intent localIntent = new Intent("android.intent.action.PICK",ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);`